# DataGridViewLinkColumn cell can't write link winforms

Tags: winforms

I have a Form with a DataGridView.

```
RMShyperlink = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewLinkColumn(); //create a link column column
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(RMShyperlink); //add to my datagrid


for(int i =0 ; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = "http://localhost"; //i set the value

  //but the value is null when I inspect it
}
```

how can I write a value to the cell?

Answer (score 0):

There has to be more information for what's causing this. If you drop a DataGridView onto a form and put this code into the Form_Load event, your code works fine.

Could there be some other setting on the DataGridView that you haven't mentioned? Are you using databinding or something else?

Comment: I can change values of text fields but not the cells that are in the column that has type DataGridViewLinkColumn

Comment: I get that. I'm saying that I can't replicate your issue on my side. I pasted your code as above and did not see any problem setting the value in the link column. What are the other settings that have been set on your DataGridView?